# Dual of Banach-valued $L^p$

Tags: banach-spaces, duality

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional  Banach space and let $p\in(1,+\infty)$. We may define $L^p(\mathbb R;X)$. Is it always true that the topological dual of $L^p(\mathbb R;X)$ is $L^{p'}(\mathbb R;X^*)$? Maybe some reflexivity or separability is needed for the Radon-Nikodym argument to work.
Is there a simple realization of  the dual of $L^1(\mathbb R;X)$?

Comment: Typo: you mean $L^{p'}({\mathbb R}, X^*)$, right?

Answer (score 9):

Diestel-Uhl, Vector measures, Section IV.1., Theorem 1:

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $1\leq p<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$.

The dual of $L^p(\mu;X)$ is $L^{p'}(\mu,X^\ast)$ if and only if $X^\ast$ has the Radon-Nikodym property.

This is especially the case if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Just to clarify: presumably there is a missing quantifier, and the full result is: the dual has the desired form for all $\sigma$-finite $(\Omega,\mu)$ if and only if $X^*$ has RNP?

Comment: Yes, I add the details to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Another important special case (where $X^*$ has the RNP) is when $X^*$ is separable.  For example, if $X$ is separable and $X^*$ is not separable, we would expect the dual of $L^{p}(\mu, X)$ to include some non-Bochner-measurable functions.

Comment: What is the Radon-Nikodym property? Is it easy to say?

Comment: The Radon-Nikodym property is a property saying that the vector-valued version of the Radon-Nikodym theorem holds true. Conjecturally it is equivalent to saying that all convex, closed, bounded sets are closed convex hulls of their extreme points.

Comment: @AndréHenriques just to add to Tomek's comment: X has RNP if and only if every bounded subset of X has the following geometric property ("dentability"): for each $r>0$ there is a point $x\in X$ that does not lie in the convex hull of $X\setminus$ (r-neighbourhood of $x$)

Comment: Here, we need only RNP for dual space $X^*$.  Stegall's characterization: $X^*$ enjoys the RNP if and only if every separable subspace of $X$ has separable dual.

Comment: And for me a Banach space $E$ has the Radon-Nikodym property if and only if every Lipschitz function $f:[0,1]\to E$ is almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: That Diestel--Uhl is a fine book.  Have a look.